# Creating A Multi-select in React that accepts values not found in dropdown options

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to create an input on my reactjs application where, I have an array of names populating a select. Here, when a user types a name that does not exit in the array used to populate the select, he should have the option to still tag this username into the selected list( indirectly a new item on the list). Also, the user needs to be able to tag multiple users.

It should work exactly like the Multiselect of react-select Component https://jedwatson.github.io/react-select/ except for the fact that, selected values also accept values which are not part of the dropdown

If there are any existing solutions to this in react, I will really love to take a look at them.

thanks and waiting for  your help

Answer (score 2):

Isn't this already supported via the [Creatable](https://react-select.com/creatable) version of the react-select?

Comment: thanks for the aid. I did not know of it. and I have been searching for it all day and I started writing mine

Comment: I seem to have a serious problem with this . when I select items and try to handle data by sending it to the state variable, It gives errors like this.state not a function, this.setState not a function. I do not understand

Comment: @NgesBrian most likely you need to bind the handler function. You should create a new question and include your code if you want help with it.